# Lookup in SharePoint

Tags: lookup-column, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I'm using Sharepoint 2010.

I have a List "Discipline" with 3 columns

```
Discipline Code          Discipline Des.-Site 1          Discipline Des.-Site 2
A                        A1                              A2                   
B                        B1                              B2
C                        C1                              C2 
.                        .                               . 
.                        .                               .
.                        .                               .
```

I have a Library "Project Documents" where I have below columns related to Discipline

"Discipline Code" (drop down from the Discipline List)

"Site" (drop down) with choices Site 1 and Site 2.

"Discipline Des." WHICH SHOULD BE AUTO POPULATED (for which i'm requesting help)

**Result Expected:** As, soon as I select the Site and Discipline Code, system should lookup the above table and bring the value for Discipline Des.

Is is possible to bring the result without Sharepoint Designer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve the cascading lookup functionality for example via the SPServices JavaScript library and the Content Editor Web Part.
See an example here:
http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript client object model to query the master list based on what is selected in the fields and populate the third field. The code can be written in Content Query Webpart without the need for SharePoint Designer.